# Delphi RAD 2010 Update to latest Indy version

Tags: delphi, updates, delphi-2010, indy, indy10

I use Delphi RAD 2010 and Indy 10.5.5. Now I'm working with IdSMTP and IdMessage. But found some issues in them work. And find information that in late version, for example in 10.5.9 this problem has gone. But on Indy official site I can't find downloads link.

Comment: These questions are always always resolved in the same way. Get the source from the tempo repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But on Indy official site I can't find downloads link.

- Go to http://www.indyproject.org
- Click on [Indy.Sockets (VCL)](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/index.aspx)
- Click on [Downloads](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/wizard/DownloadWizard.aspx)
- Click on [Version 10](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/Files/Indy10.aspx)
- Click on [Development Snapshot](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx)
- Click on [Development Snapshot](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx) (again)
- Click on [Indy via SVN](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.aspx), [Fulgan.com](http://indy.fulgan.com/), or [precompiled binaries](http://www.mjfreelancing.com/indy.htm).

Comment: Update: few years later most links are broken but the logic stil holds. Make sure to read the installation instructions on download page. http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx There is a GIT repo now, and for Delphi 2010 just open the VER210 .groupproj there is no .bat file.

Comment: Currently there is no working download link, and there are no releases on github. I love this project but it seems like it's trying to actively discourage downloads, which would be fine if GetIt was near usable.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera see https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/, and https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/328, and https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/134. It is not that Indy is trying to dissuade downloading. It is that there are some technical issues preventing it from being easier than it should be, and lack of time and manpower to maintain it properly (I'm only 1 person, with a busy schedule outside of Indy. I wish the community was more involved).

Comment: I'll add a pull request to add a README.md to the repository root then :-)

Comment: Btw - is "master" stable enough to use on production?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera in general, yes. As noted, Indy doesn't really have stable releases, and never has. Fixes and such typically go straight into `master`, but I try hard not to break `master`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out Indy from the public subversion repository.

Detailed instructions are at http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/svn.en.aspx